# How to create a datetime indexed pandas DataFrame with hypothesis library?

Tags: python, pandas, pytest, python-hypothesis

I am trying to create a `pandas DataFrame` with the `hypothesis` library for code testing purporses with the following code:

```
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import columns, data_frames
from hypothesis.extra.numpy import datetime64_dtypes

@given(data_frames(index=datetime64_dtypes(max_period='Y', min_period='s'),
                   columns=columns("A B C".split(), dtype=int)))
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
E           TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not iterable
```

I suspect that this is because when I construct the `DataFrame` for `index=` I only pass a `datetime` element and not a `ps.Series` all with type `datetime` for example. Even if this is the case (I am not sure), still I am not sure how to work with the `hypothesis` library in order to achieve my goal.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code and what the solution would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the above error was because, [`data_frames`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html#hypothesis.extra.pandas.data_frames) requires an index containing a *strategy* elements inside such as [`indexes`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html#hypothesis.extra.pandas.indexes) for an `index=` input. Instead, the above `datetime64_dtypes` only provides a *strategy* element, but not in an index format.

To fix this we provide the index first and then the strategy element inside the index like so:

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies 
@given(data_frames(index=indexes(strategies.datetimes()),
                   columns=columns("A B C".split(), dtype=int)))
```

Note that in order to get `datetime` we use [`datetimes()`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.datetimes).

Comment: I am guessing you are using `hypothesis.extra.pandas.indexes`? I am getting this error: "TypeError: indexes() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given", I guess the API changed so you need to use `indexes(elements=...)`