# Hypothesis create column with pd.datetime dtype in given test-dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, python-hypothesis

I want to test whether a certain method can handle different dates in a pandas dataframe, which it takes as an argument. The following example should clarify what kind of setup I want. In the example `column('Date', dtype=pd.datetime)` does not work for creating a date column in the test dataframe:

```
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import column, data_frames
import pandas as pd
from unittest import TestCase

class TestExampleClass(TestCase):

    @given(data_frames([column('A', dtype=str), column('B', dtype=int),column('Date', dtype=pd.datetime)]))
    def test_example_test_method(self, dataframe):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Any ideas? I am aware of [How to create a datetime indexed pandas DataFrame with hypothesis library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072179/how-to-create-a-datetime-indexed-pandas-dataframe-with-hypothesis-library), but it did not help for my specific case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dtype="datetime64[ns]"` instead of `dtype=pd.datetime`.

---

I've [opened an issue to look into this in more detail and give helpful error messages](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/3518) when passed `pd.datetime`, `datetime`, or a unitless datetime dtype; this kind of confusion isn't the user experience we want to offer!